# How to use dots in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am using javascript to read the data of my firebase and to see it in an html. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to read it in the form of dots and it does not read it properly.

I tried to do it as a table but it does not work

This is my code in html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #008000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dot2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dot3 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
    </head>

<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fconf.js"></script>

<div id="div" style="text-align:center">
  <h1> A</h1>

  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>

</div>
<div  style="text-align:center">

  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<script src="view.js"></script>
<script src="back.js"></script>
<button onclick="back()">back</button> <br>

</body>
</html>
```

And This is my javascript code:

```
.dot2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}




setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
        }, 3000);

    var database = firebase.database().ref().child('/test/A');  

        database.once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var val = childSnapshot.val();
                //content +='<tr>';

                  if (val.Distancem2 > 15 &&  val.DistanceMiddle1 > 15 && val.DistanceMiddle3 > 15){

                content +='<div>';
                  content += '<span>' + class="dot2"+ '</span>';
                  content += '<span>' + class="dot2" + '</span>';
                   content += '<span>' + class="dot2" + '</span>';
                    content += '<span>' + class="dot2" + '</span>';
                   content +='</div>';
                }

                });
            $('#div').append(content);
```

This is what it shows me:
[image: Results]

This is what I want it to show:
[image: Expected results]

Comment: Add a snippet for easy test please.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got a typo:

```
if if (val.Distancem2 > 15 &&  val.DistanceMiddle1 > 15 && val.DistanceMiddle3 > 15)
```

'if if', just remove one.

Comment: I removed it, I still have the same problem

Comment: Your class attribute is out side the span. content += '<span>' + class="dot2"+ '</span>';  Try <span class="dot2"></span>